# Como é criado e configurado o banco de dados de uma aplicação WEB?

Tags: banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, crud

Como é criado e configurado o *banco de dados* de uma aplicação *WEB*? É implementada rotinas responsáveis pela criação do banco de dados e de todo **CRUD** na própria aplicação quando a mesma é iniciada pela primeira vez no servidor ou deve fazer este procedimento através do próprio **SGBD** ou alguma interface que provê acesso ao banco?

Geralmente em aplicações Desktop o banco de dados é criando e configurado em tempo de execução quando a aplicação é iniciada pela primeira vez ou este processo é feito por um instalador. Com aplicações *WEB* ocorre da mesma forma?

Comment: Não vou comentar em respostas, porque não tenho muita informação, mas no meu ver, isso é bem relativo. Geralmente, as maiores aplicações pra web disponibilizam uma pasta install, que tem todo o script de instalação e configuração da aplicação. O sistema principal apenas identifica se existe um arquivo config e uma pasta install, com isso ele saberá se a aplicação já foi instalada ou não, e se não foi, redireciona pra pasta install. Lá será possível validar os requisitos mínimos necessários para a aplicação, bem como fazer a coleta de dados importantes como o banco de dados e, geralmente

Comment: Os dados do primeiro administrador que será cadastrado no sistema. Como eu disse, dependendo da aplicação, isso não é um código pequeno, o que se colocado na aplicação principal, iria deixar mais bagunçado e pra beneficio nenhum. E aí não estamos nem levando em consideração o problema da segurança, já que os arquivos de instalação iriam conter informações importantes sobre o sistema, principalmente sobre o SGBD. Por isso, também, que as aplicações solicitam que o usuário delete a pasta install após concluir o processo.